# Gradle test module for Android module

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, gradle, gradle-android-test-plugi

I start develop new `Android` project using gradle as assemeler. I need to set test enviroment for it.
I know way to set test as flavor of my project. But I want to have two different module: `app`, `appTest`. `app` is my project I develop and appTest is tests for it. More than that I need to have some flavors of my app, I want to choose what flavor to test.

I want to have follow structure in my project:

```
--Project

----app
------main
------flavor1
------flavor2

----appTest
------main
```

It is clearly for me how create project and test project for it in `Eclipse`. But I confused how to do it in `Idea`. How I can create `appTest` module in `Idea` with gradle as assembler? And is it possible to passing test project for flavor I choose?